# html - one link opens two windows

Tags: javascript, html

so every time I go to pornhub.com, and I click on a video, two windows open. 1) the video I'm trying to watch, and 2) another one with a live stream. I'm just trying to figure out if this is done via html or javascript... Is it possible to specify two links with html only, or do you need js?

Comment: Interesting choice of example there...

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript for opening multiple windows at the same time. `window.open()` method can be used. For example, see: http://jsfiddle.net/NJXPD/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is required to open two windows at once

Answer (score 0):

You will need JavaScript, it is impossible with HTML only. If you try to set one link to have two different locations to be redirected to, you will only be taken to the first address.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CYwqk/

Answer (score 0):

You can only open the second window with JS, they didn't do
`<a><a>The Porn</a></a>` and have it open two links.